# CSVHelper C# Load from My object

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dictionary, csvhelper

Hi I am trying to use CSVHelper to simply export to CSV a list of objects.
(http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper)

So I have this:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = GetAllEmployees();
```

I created this map:

```
public sealed class EmployeeExport: CsvClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeExport()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Map(m => m.Account.AccountName);
        Map(m => m.LabourChargeType.LabourChargeTypeName);
    }
}
```

How can I load the ExployeeExport class with my employeeList and simply export to CSV according to my Map class?

Also how can I convert my Employee.Minutes to "hh:mm" and creating a new column inexistent called "Duration"

Thanks

Comment: Is Employee.Minutes a TimeSpan

Comment: Where can I find a list of TimeSpan.ToString formats? such as "hh\:mm:\ss"? Why is it different from normal datetime formats in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mapping is for reading CSV. you will need to include "using System.IO"

**EDIT:**

```
        // Populate your employeeList
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("foo.csv"); //foo.csv is the file you are saving to
        var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
        foreach (var employee in employeeList)
        {
            csv.WriteField(employee.Id);
            csv.WriteField(employee.Date.ToShortDateString());
            csv.WriteField(employee.Account.AccountName);
            csv.WriteField(employee.LabourChargeType.LabourChargeTypeName);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
        textWriter = null;
```

**REFERENCE:** http://csharp.net-informations.com/file/csharp-textwriter.htm

Comment: Cool, but I would like somehow to use the Map, anyway.. do you know how can I take this csv and convert in bytes to return a file save?

Comment: Edited to answer you question